# Laravel Eloquent double relation with condition

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have three models with following data:

1. Product

   - id
   - name
   - description
2. Variant

   - id
   - colour
   - type
   - private
   - product_id
3. Image

   - url
   - variant_id

So the relations are:

- Product hasMany Variants
- Variant hasMany Images

I need to get a collection of all the Variants, including the parent Product because I also need its name and including the images related to the Variant, with the conditions (on Variant) ->where('type', 'OPT') and ->where('private', false).

I tried to do it with a raw SQL query but I need to loop through Variant's images in the blade template, so I need a collection. How can I put all together without running too many queries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have these relations on your `Variant` model:

```
public function product()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
}

public function images()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Image::class);
}
```

Then you can do:

```
$collection = Variant::with('product', 'images')
    ->where('type', 'OPT')
    ->where('private', false)
    ->get();
```